# Creating automatically csv file from excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have the following workbook:

[image]

My goal is to automatically generate csv file on workbook closing event, as following:

[image]

So, that only IDs + SurveyDate would be in the csv file
(No - ProgramName, Gender, Age, Question1, Question2, header)

Currently I record macro manually and removing the header and all non ID columns

But, potentially, Question3 or Question4 could be added into this spreadsheet and in that case - macro needed to be re-recorded

I am wondering if there a way to generate csv not with the Macro recording, but the way - so no matter how many extra questions added into the Form - they'd automatically be removed from csv - and only QuestionsID would be added (Question3ID, Question4ID, etc...)

Comment: You'd need to loop through the headers and check if the header is `Like *ID` which means, if the header ends in  ID. If not, delete the column.